# MinBy does not return any result Apache Storm

Tags: scala, apache-storm, aggregation

I have built Storm topology with data retrieval from Kafka. And I would like to build an aggregation with counting minimum for each of the batches on one of the fields. I tried to use maxBy function on the stream, however, it does not display any results, although the data is flowing through the system and output function worked with other aggregations. How can it be implemented differently or what can be fixed in the current implementation?

Here is my current implementation:

```
val tridentTopology = new TridentTopology()

    val stream = tridentTopology.newStream("kafka_spout",
      new KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque(spoutConfig))
      .map(new ParserMapFunction, new Fields("created_at", "id", "text", "source", "timestamp_ms",
        "user.id", "user.name", "user.location", "user.url", "user.description", "user.followers_count",
        "user.friends_count", "user.favorite_count", "user.lang", "entities.hashtags"))
      .maxBy("user.followers_count")
      .map(new OutputFunction)
```

My custom output function:

```
class OutputFunction extends MapFunction{

  override def execute(input: TridentTuple): Values = {
    val values = input.getValues.asScala.toList.toString
    println(s"TWEET: $values")
    new Values(values)
  }
}
```

Comment: A String is not a valid argument for `maxBy`.  Did you mean `maxBy(new Fields("user.followers_count"))`?

Comment: I use String because there is a compiler error with Fields. Max signature looks like this with Storm 2.1.0: 
    `@param inputFieldName input field name
      @return the new stream with this operation.
    public Stream maxBy(String inputFieldName) `